# How can I make a function to program Chrome to set itself the "Break" status at my workplace

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am working in a call center, and everytime i go to the toilet, I have to change my status to "Break" using a dropdown menu from the google chrome page(internal website).
I can use inspect and see all the classes and button ids but for some reasons it's not working, it give me the error "undefined".

```
function Myfunc (){
    var button1 = document.getElementById("_10erop07");
    button1.click();
}
```

How Can i make a script, that at a certain hour, I enter code here will automatically trigger at the certain hour.

Basically, I want the script to click on the dropdown and select the "Break" status.

Any ideas how can I do that?

Comment: Without more information about the HTML elements it's difficult to help.  If the error is `undefined` then `getElementById` is probably not finding anything and hence you can't `click` it

Comment: for running small script on specific page you can use this plugin or something like that :
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-style-script/ecjfaoeopefafjpdgnfcjnhinpbldjij?hl=en 

and for drop down box is better share with us your dropdown input html here .

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done using [Bookmarklets](https://gist.github.com/caseywatts/c0cec1f89ccdb8b469b1)

follow the steps in the guide link above.
your javascript code should look something like this

```
javascript:(
    function(){
        // YOUR CODE SHOULD BE HERE
    }
)();
```

> But make sure to click the bookmarklet when you are in the website

I hope that helps.